# Python String split Formatting

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of string like this and I want to print first item and second item together and in next line first and third item together

> ['Vento Power', 'Quinoxyfen', 'Myclobutanil']

to:

> ['Vento Power','Quinoxyfen']
>   ['Vento Power','Myclobutanil']

Comment: post your code, in few a seconds you going to be down-voted...I recommend you to read the website guideline for posting questions

Comment: That's very necessary. Please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import itertools
l = ['Vento Power', 'Quinoxyfan', 'Miclobutanil']
for i in [list(i) for i in itertools.combinations(l,r=2) if 'Vento Power' in i]:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
['Vento Power', 'Quinoxyfan']
['Vento Power', 'Miclobutanil']
```

Comment: thanks. But if, we have more than 100 list items with different strings  ? ['Acrobat','choloro','Cyper'] , ['Alpha','Carfen','Mancozeb','Carben']

Comment: @GaganDeepSingh It will still work but around 15 seconds

Comment: for items in Substance_Active :
        if Substance_Active not in agre:
            agre.append(items)
            #a=[items]
            for i in [list(i) for i in itertools.combinations(items,r=2) if agre[1] in i]:
                print(i) this is my code please let me know where is the error, it prints nothing for me

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```py
res=list([el[0], el_inner] for el in x for el_inner in el[1:])
```

Where `x` is your input list of lists

On sample data:

```py
x=[["a", "b", "c", "x"], ["a", "g"], ["x", "y", "z"], ["x", "q"], ["a", "b", "c"]]

y=list([el[0], el_inner] for el in x for el_inner in el[1:])

print(x)
print(y)
```

Output:

```py
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'x'], ['a', 'g'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'q'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['a', 'x'], ['a', 'g'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'z'], ['x', 'q'], ['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c']]
```